# Asp.Net GridView Retrieving cell values of each row through for loop and hiding empty columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I know variations of this question have been asked a lot and I have been looking for answers for a long time and have tried many different blocks of code. Here is what I have right now which I am looping through from 0 to gridview1.rows.count-1. This code is in the RowDataBound Event.

```
    Dim test As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        test = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells.Item(e.Row.RowIndex).Text.ToString
        If test = "&nbsp;" Then
            e.Row.Cells(i).Visible = False
        End If

    Next
```

Every time I get the error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index on this line

```
   test = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells.Item(e.Row.RowIndex).Text.ToString
```

However, I think the error is just because I am going outside of the row range but can't figure out how to fix it. How can I successfully check each cell of all the rows and columns and hide the columns that return nothing.

I can now hide all of the actual cells within each column that is blank with this

```
 Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As      System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
  Dim GridView1 As GridView = FormView1.FindControl("GridView1")
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
      For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
       Dim strtest As String = row.Cells(i).Text.ToString
         If strtest = "&nbsp;" Then
         row.Cells(i).Visible = False
         End If      
        Next
    Next
```

But it still won't let me hide the columns because with autogeneratecolumns it doesn't recognize that any columns are there so the code, 
    GridView1.Columns(i).visible = false
Throws the out of range error because there is no range of columns

Comment: In which event do you have this code? In `RowDataBound` or elsewhere?

Comment: RowDataBound, Sorry I meant to include that in the question

Comment: Is this looping working for at least some iterations?

Comment: Yes it will return the text values from the cells and assign them to the variable test without problem until the error.

Comment: It may help to know as well that my grid view columns are autogenerated because I have around 20 different SqlDataSources that I am switching between in the gridview.

Comment: It it also looks like after the values are returned from the first row, the rest of the values are all null which I know that there is more than one row that should be returned from the DataSource.

Comment: try using If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then //your code

Comment: When I placed  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then  outside my code it didn't change anything. Although it appears that in my nested for loop, when i'm debugging, it doesn't look like it is actually executing the lines of code inside my nested for loop, it just skips over them.

Comment: When I assign the columns.count Dim test3 As Integer = dgv.Columns.Count I get test3 = &H0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys I finally found the correct way to do this, at least a way that works for me. So you have to use the row.cells.count -1 to actually get the count of your columns when you have autogeneratecolumns set to true and in order to iterate through your columns to set them to visible = false, you must use

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).visible = False
```

Here is my Final code and hopefully this will help a lot of people out that have the same problem, Thank you all for your help and answers

```
 Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim GridView1 As GridView = FormView1.FindControl("GridView1")
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            Dim strtest As String = row.Cells(i).Text.ToString
            If strtest = "&nbsp;" Then
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Visible = False
                row.Cells(i).Visible = False

            End If

        Next
    Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row As GridViewRow in GridView1.rows // rows
dim someval as String
 for x= 0 to  GridView1.Columns.Count // cols 
  if someval=  = row.Cells[x].Text;
 GridView1.Columns(x).Visible = false;
end if
 next x
Next
```

manually typed pls check for typos'

Comment: This code is reading in the values correctly however, only for the first column. And it is only set to remove column(3). How can i loop through this so that I can check the entire gridview and remove the column dynamically where it would look like        GridView1.Columns(i).Visible = false

Comment: add another loop to get the all the cells then turn off whichever you want , i'll update the answer in a min

Comment: This code throws the error that the index was out of range on the GridView1.Columns(x).Visible = False

Comment: Could this error possibly be coming from the fact that I am autogenerating my columns and they haven't been created yet? If so, How would I fix this

Comment: depends where u using the code, if its' after the grid is on the page, then the auto gen is not the problem GridView1.Columns(x -1 ), should fix it

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help, I will try this out tomorrow and go from there.

Comment: sorry GridView1.Columns.Count-1 as count assumes starting is 1 but it's 0 so it count-1

Comment: even after changing it to GridView1.Columns(x-1) and Changing the for loop condition to GridView1.Columns.Count - 1 it is still throwing the error. The code is placed after the datasource has been bound and is inside the FormView1 DataBound event. I believe that because of the auto gen it still does not recognize that there are any columns created. Do I need to use this code in a different event?

Comment: Actually now it is not throwing the error however, it does not execute the code inside the For x = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1. While debugging it just continues to iterate through the outside of that loop without stepping to the lines of code inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

But I would probably point out that you seem to be reading through the entire grid every time you bind a row, which seems unnecessary. Rather you can have a separate method which you can call after the gridview is `databound` to hide your columns.

Put the below code in a function and call this function after the databinding for the grid.

```
Private Sub CheckForEmptyValues()
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = GridView1

    For r As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
       For c As Integer = 0 To dgv.ColumnCount - 1
            Dim cellValue as string = dgv.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value
            If cellValue = "&nbsp;" Then
               dgv.Rows(r).Cells(c).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What would I replace dgvPartByCategory with and in Cells("PartID") is that just specifying a specific column called PartID?

Comment: I'm trying to search through all of the columns not just one

Comment: Ok, edited my answer with the code required for the separate `Sub`. It's unnecessary to check for all grid rows and cells in the `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: Also you may have check for null values like `If cellValue Is Nothing AndAlso value Is DBNull.Value Then`

Comment: the variable r is declared twice and throws a Local variable is already declared error

Comment: I think I'm not using that row reference and may not be needed. Edited code now.

Comment: It's not executing the lines of code inside the inner for loop. Is this because I am auto generating my columns and they are created yet?

Comment: When I assign the columns.count                                                                                 Dim test3 As Integer = dgv.Columns.Count        I get test3 = &H0

Comment: I have created the function and I am calling it in the Page_LoadComplete event but it is still not actually executing the lines of code inside my for loops

Comment: Please note you have to call this function after you have databound the grid and after all columns have been generated. You may put a break point in the code and check how many columns exist (if any) and why it's not stepping into the for loop.

Comment: What Event would I be able to put it in, I figured page_LoadComplete would be after.

Comment: And it is showing that Test3 = dgv.columns.count = &H0

Comment: dgv.rows.count = &H14